# multiple elements in web.config - asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Currently my web.config has this:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" />
    <add key="DBServer" />
    <add key="DBUserName" />
    <add key="DBPwd" />
    <add key="DB" />
  </appSettings>
```

If i have to connect to multiple db's I would like my web.config to have the following

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" />
    <add key="DBServer" />
    <add key="DBUserName" />
    <add key="DBPwd" />
    <add key="DB" />
  </appSettings>

<!--This section needs to hold data for another db server -->
 <appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" />
    <add key="DBServer" />
    <add key="DBUserName" />
    <add key="DBPwd" />
    <add key="DB" />
  </appSettings>
```

The key names should be the same. Or is having multiple connection string sections the way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`<connectionStrings>` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(VS.80).aspx) for this, it's *exactly* what it was designed to do :)

You can find more resources on MSDN for [how to access your connection strings in this section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx).

Comment: Beat me to it. Let me just add that http://connectionstrings.com/ is an excellent resource for determining how to correctly combine connection credentials into a connection string.

Comment: @kbrimington - +1 - That is indeed an excellent resource, especially when dealing with unfamiliar environments.